# Unable to replicate and sync files in clustering of tomcat using Zen-Load balancer

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, cluster-computing, load-balancing

I am using Zen-Load balancer to setup clustering of two tomcat servers. I have deployed applications on both of the servers. Session replication is working fine as imagined in clustering. But i have a problem with file replication in both of the servers. Suppose i browse a image from portal on node 1 and upload it.

When request is going to server 2 i am not getting that image on Node 2. Need suggestion how can i replicate these files on both of the servers so that they will work in sync with each other for files and log files.

Do i need to make any changes in Tomcat or Do i need to change anything on Zen-Load balancer.